# $\mathbb{Z}/(p)^n$ does not contain a field if $n \geq 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $\mathbb{Z}/(p)^n$ does not contain a field if $n \geq 2$ and cannot be made into a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ in a compatible way with its Abelian structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$ does not contain a field, suppose to the contrary that it contains the field $K$. Think of $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$ as the integers from $0$ to $p^n-1$, under the usual addition and multiplication modulo $p^n$.

Let $a$ be a non-zero element of $K$. Note that $a$ cannot be divisible by $p$, else a power of $a$ would be the $0$-element of $K$. For any positive integer $m$, the object $ma$ must be in $K$.  But then $K$ is all of $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$, which is impossible, since if $n\gt 2$ then $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$ is not even an integral domain.

Comment: @seaturtles:  If $a$ is in $K$, its (multiplicative) inverse $b$ is in $K$, and therefore the product $ab$ is in $K$.

Comment: I am not setting $a$ equal to $1$. I am saying that $a$ is invertible in $K$, and $b$ is its inverse in $K$, the product $ab$ is in $K$, and is the unit element of $K$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, poor notation. I will modify the answer to make sure it is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Well, $\;R:=\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z\;,\;\;n>1\;$ cannot be a vector space over $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ since, for example

$$\overline1:=1+p^n\Bbb Z\;\;:\;\;0\neq \underbrace{\overline 1+\overline1+\ldots+\overline1}_{p\;\text{times}}=p\cdot(1+p^n\Bbb Z)=0$$

since $\;p=0\;$ in $\;\Bbb F_p\;$